# How to convert JSON data to Array in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am getting Json data from result as following,

```
   var chartData1 = [
     {\"Action\":\"Twitter\",\"value\":\"1.00\",\"platform\":\"2\"},
     {\"Action\":\"WhatsApp\",\"value\":\"1.00\",\"platform\":\"3\"},
     {\"Action\":\"Messaging\",\"value\":\"1.00\",\"platform\":\"4\"}
     ]
```

I want to convert it to following,

```
   var chartData2 =  [
    ['Action', 'value', 'platform'],
    ['Twitter', '1.00', 2],
    ['WhatsApp', '1.00', 3],
    ['Messaging', 'WhatsApp', 4],
   ]
```

I have used different methods like parseJSON,map,etc , but i could not get expected results.

```
Can you help me out from this.
```

Comment: Can you remove garbage `\\` from your data?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you first need to parse valid JSON string containing your data and then convert each row with object to array. And prepend whole array with array with column names. Following code will exactly do that:

```
var chartDataString = "[{\"Action\":\"Twitter\",\"value\":\"1.00\",\"platform\":\"2\"},{\"Action\":\"WhatsApp\",\"value\":\"1.00\",\"platform\":\"3\"},{\"Action\":\"Messaging\",\"value\":\"1.00\",\"platform\":\"4\"}]";

var chartData = JSON.parse(chartDataString);

var keys = [];
var data = [];
var row;
for (var i = 0; i < chartData.length; i++) {
    row = [];
    for (var key in chartData[i]) {
        if (i === 0) {
            keys.push(key);   
        }

        row.push(chartData[i][key]);
    }

    if (i === 0) {
        data.push(keys);   
    }

    data.push(row);
}

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

The following will convert it to an array, providing that it is already parsed as an object.

```
var chartData2 = Object.keys(chartData1).map(function(k) { return chartData1[k] });

console.log(chartData2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the most ideal here is to map original array to new structure:

```js
var chartData1 = [
     {"Action":"Twitter","value":"1.00","platform":"2"},
     {"Action":"WhatsApp","value":"1.00","platform":"3"},
     {"Action":"Messaging","value":"1.00","platform":"4"}
];

var result = chartData1.map(function(el) {
    return [el.Action, el.value, el.platform];
});
result.unshift(['Action', 'value', 'platform']);


alert(JSON.stringify(result, null, 4));
```